# Analyzing reflected and transformed variables

Tags: spss, multiple-regression

I want to perform multiple linear regression on my variables; since my dependent variable was negatively skewed, I reflected it and then I log transformed it. 
My independent variables was positively skewed, so I only log transformed them.

My first question is: **after performing multiple linear regression on my variables, should I interpret results adversely?**

I mean: if an independent variable has a positive beta, I say it has a negative effect on dependent variable; and if an independent variable has a negative beta, I say it has a positive effect on dependent variable?

My second question is: **my adjusted $R^2$ is $0.35$, is that good enough to say that my model is acceptable?**

Comment: 1. The data does not need to be normal, the residuals need to be. 2. What is a "good enough" $R^2$ varies by field. 3. Both these questions have been asked before (many times).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. sorry if I asked duplicate question! I'll search in site more carefully next time.

Comment: You could search the site now, @PotentialScientist ;-). Re Peter's first point, you might try reading this thread: [what-if-residuals-are-normally-distributed-but-y-is-not](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/), eg. In addition, your question is not entirely clear: by "analyze", do you mean *interpret*? You refer to both sets of variables as "dependent variables", might one of them be *independent*?

Comment: yeah; thanks a lot; I edited my question. I'll take a look at the link. by the way, I checked the P-P plot of my variables and I saw that residuals are not normally distributed ; then what should I do now? do I need to transform my variables?